# c# wpf - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I don't know whats wrong with my code and how can i solve it.

```
public class ExampleViewModel<T> : ViewModelBase where T : IAppointment
{
    private Uri appointmentsSource;
    private ObservableCollection<T> appointments;

    public ICommand AppointmentCreatedCommand { get; set; }

    public Uri AppointmentsSource
    {
        get { return this.appointmentsSource; }
        set { this.appointmentsSource = value; }
    }

    public ExampleViewModel()
    {
        this.AppointmentCreatedCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnAppointmentCreatedCommandExecute);
    }

    private void OnAppointmentCreatedCommandExecute(object obj)
    {
        var createdAppointment = ((AppointmentCreatedEventArgs)(obj)).CreatedAppointment as Appointment;
        ObservableAppointmentCollection apps = System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(File.OpenRead("../../Appointments.xaml")) as ObservableAppointmentCollection;
        apps.Add(createdAppointment);
        File.WriteAllText("../../Appointments.xaml", System.Windows.Markup.XamlWriter.Save(apps));
        string text = File.ReadAllText("../../Appointments.xaml");
        text = text.Replace("<Appointment.TimeZone><s:TimeZoneInfo /></Appointment.TimeZone>", " ");
        File.WriteAllText("../../Appointments.xaml", text);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<T> Appointments
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.appointments == null)
            {
                this.appointments = new ObservableCollection<T>(LoadAppointmentsSource(this.AppointmentsSource));
            }
            return this.appointments;
        }
    }

    protected static IEnumerable<T> LoadAppointmentsSource(Uri appointmentsSource)
    {
        if (appointmentsSource != null)
        {
            IEnumerable<T> appointments = Application.LoadComponent(appointmentsSource) as IEnumerable<T>;
            return appointments;
        }
        return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
    }

    private static DateTime GetStart(T a)
    {
        return a.Start.Date;
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="AppointmentCreated">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding AppointmentCreatedCommand, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

there is an error

> NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
>
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

on

`var createdAppointment = ((AppointmentCreatedEventArgs)(obj)).CreatedAppointment as Appointment;`

everytime i create appointment in my `RadScheduleView` (Telerik), it was supposed to create appointment then write it in the `Appointments.xaml`.

Comment: check if obj is null or what is the type if it is not null.

Comment: is obj of type AppointmentCreatedEventArgs??

Comment: you should also post the code of the caller of OnAppointmentCreatedCommandExecute. Obviously, `obj` is null, but we need to figure out why :)

Comment: @FabioSalvalai i put all my code in my ViewModel there, im so stuck here

Answer (score 1):

Seeing your XAML and the types you are using in your command, I think you are confusing *Commands* and *Events*.

Commands are a way to execute a method upon one single predetermined action, usually hitting a button (typically by a click, a tap or a key stroke) whereas events are a way for an object to react to all sorts of conditions. Typically events expose many events, whereas there can be only one single command on a user control.

Now, the big difference here is that on an event, the sender populates and passes an `eventArgs` object, containing details on the nature of the situation which triggered the event. As for the command, this does not happen. It is possible to pass a parameter to the method which will handle the execution of a command when triggered, but you have to choose that object yourself. The way you choose the object to be passed is by means of a data binding, pretty much like the `Command` itself is bound, but with the `CommandParameter` attribute instead of `Command`.

```
CommandParameter="{Binding ...}"
```

Comment: i put the XAML code there. btw there is an error `'DSSchedule.DelegateCommand<Telerik.Windows.Controls.AppointmentCreatedEventArgs>' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments`

Comment: DelegateCommand accepts an Action<T>. make sure `OnAppointmentCreatedCommandExecute` matches this by changing the type of obj. (I edited the answer)

Comment: change the type to? i need to changet the `(object obj)`?

Comment: Well,  yes,  to AppointmentCreatedEventArgs.  That's the type of the object your CommandParameter binds to,  right?

Comment: same error occurred in `this.AppointmentCreatedCommand = new DelegateCommand<AppointmentCreatedEventArgs>(OnAppointmentCreatedCommandExecute);` btw i create `class DelegateCommand<T>
    {
    }` in my ViewModel

Comment: You updated your question with the XAML, and I see you didn't bind the CommandBinding attribute. How do you tell your DelegateCommand what should be the object to pass to it ?

Comment: i think i did with `Command="{Binding AppointmentCreatedCommand, Mode=TwoWay}"`? what should i do? the `'DSSchedule.DelegateCommand<Telerik.Windows.Controls.AppointmentCreatedEventArg‌​s>' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments` still occurred.

Comment: Oh, I see. I assumed you were using Prism's `DelegateCommand`, but you're not.What implementation of `ICommand` do you use ?

Comment: Commands are _not_ events_. Your obj is null because you never tell your implementation of `ICommand`what object to pass to `Execute(Object)`. Read the following blog post to understand more about how Commanding works, especially the part called **Passing parameter to the Command**  (https://kishore1021.wordpress.com/2011/10/08/basics-of-command-binding-using-icommand/)

Answer (score 0):

In this line :

`var createdAppointment = ((AppointmentCreatedEventArgs)(obj)).CreatedAppointment as Appointment;`

Check for null value in obj , and CreatedAppointment. It looks like either of them are not having their values set.